# Sorting rows in cross query Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a cross query in Access with an SQL:

```
TRANSFORM Tab1.Income AS Income
SELECT Tab1.Month
FROM Tab1
GROUP BY Tab1.Month
PIVOT Tab1.Group;
```

Months are string, not a number, and are in alphabetical order. I want to sort them manually.
In the normal query, I used a Switch() function which works perfectly. But in the cross query I've got an alert that ORDER BY and GROUP BY are mutually exclusive.

I would be grateful for any idea, how to sort them in query. However, if it's not possible, maybe they can be sorted in the report because this is more important.

Comment: Any sorting should be _removed_ from a query when used as source for report and replaced with sorting in the report.

Comment: Please show your attempt with `SWITCH` and post exact error message you receive.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to sort by rows in a report? I can only sort them desc or incs, just like in query.

Comment: ASCENDING or DESCENDING are the only ways to sort. Use report Sorting & Grouping design tool. Pick a field or build an expression to use for sort.

Answer (score 0):

Options:

1. calculate month number field to use as primary group criteria, include it along with month name as Row Headers and if this is a multi-year dataset perhaps should also include year as a Row Header - hopefully there is a full date field available to extract date parts from
2. report design can use expression to dictate sort order

Month is a reserved word and advise not to use reserved words as object names.